# Error when searching for the length of a list

Tags: python-3.x

**[Edit: Solved, i was calling the same function from another place in the code with wrong input arguments, creating this error]**

I am new to python and after some search i've decided to post my problem..

My function takes *args as input: a variable number of lists

In this function i use a for loop to read all lists and try to get len(each_list).
I then get the error TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

I've tried to find the problem by myself but i don't understand the behavior

If i do:

```py
def myfunction(* args):
    for p in args:
        print(isinstance(p, list))
        print(type(p))
        print(p)
```

I'll get: True + class 'list' + [value1, value2, ... etc]

But if i add one line to get the length (last one)

```py
def myfunction(* args):
    for p in args:
        print(isinstance(p, list))
        print(type(p))
        print(p)
        a = len(p)
```

I'll get: False + class 'numpy.float64' + error (i understand it is not iterable)

I call the function as:

```
All_lists = [list1, list2, list3]
myfunction(All_lists)
# I've also tried myfunction(*All_lists)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Well what are `list1`, `list2`, and `list3`? Are they of type `numpy.float64`?

Comment: `list1`, `list2`, `list3` are all lists (same length)
They all contains: class 'numpy.float64'


So in summary i have:
`list[list[numpy.float64], list[numpy.float64], list[numpy.float64]]`


And the function gets (after testing):
`tuple[list[numpy.float64], list[numpy.float64], list[numpy.float64]]`

Comment: Yes, and the compiler is telling you that you cannot use `len()` on the `numpy.float64` arrays, so you must use a different function or the `numpy.ndarray.size` attribute for each array or enter a list that you can use `len()` on. `len()` is attempting to figure out the number of combined elements in all the lists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `len(p)` for the length of arguments list

```
def myfunction(* args):
    for p in args:
        print(isinstance(p, list))
        print(type(p))
        print(p)
        print(len(p))

myfunction([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ])
#True
#<class 'list'>
#[1, 2, 3]
#3
```